# plt.bar -> TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'float' objects

Tags: numpy, matplotlib

I have a variable `x_axis` that represents a numpy array:

```
array(['administrator', 'retired', 'lawyer', 'none', 'student',
       'technician', 'programmer', 'salesman', 'homemaker', 'executive',
       'doctor', 'entertainment', 'marketing', 'writer', 'scientist',
       'educator', 'healthcare', 'librarian', 'artist', 'other', 'engineer'], 
      dtype='|S13')
```

... and my `y_axis` looks like this:

```
array([ 79,  14,  12,   9, 196,  27,  66,  12,   7,  32,   7,  18,  26,
        45,  31,  95,  16,  51,  28, 105,  67])
```

When I try to plot them:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.bar(x_axis,y_axis)
```

I receive the error:

```
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'float' objects
```

---

**Note:**

I've seen 'similar' questions, but not specifically asking about this error in reference to matplotlib.bar.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is because `bar` needs x-coordinates, but your `x_axis` is an array of strings. So, `bar` does not know where to plot the bars. What you need is the following:

```
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

y_axis = np.array([ 79,  14,  12,   9, 196,  27,  66,  12,   7,  32,   7,  18,  26,
        45,  31,  95,  16,  51,  28, 105,  67])

x_labels = np.array(['administrator', 'retired', 'lawyer', 'none', 'student',
       'technician', 'programmer', 'salesman', 'homemaker', 'executive',
       'doctor', 'entertainment', 'marketing', 'writer', 'scientist',
       'educator', 'healthcare', 'librarian', 'artist', 'other', 'engineer'], 
      dtype='|S13')

w = 3
nitems = len(y_axis)
x_axis = np.arange(0, nitems*w, w)    # set up a array of x-coordinates

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)
ax.bar(x_axis, y_axis, width=w, align='center')
ax.set_xticks(x_axis);
ax.set_xticklabels(x_labels, rotation=90);
plt.show()
```